# how to proceed encryption and decryption?

Tags: java, encryption

Assume values as:

```
int p=9; // (any odd no)
int q=5; // (any odd no)
int e=3;
int n=p*q;
```

I read text file and convert the contents into byte array by this code:

```
        while ((eof_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        byte_array = eof_line.getBytes();
        String decoded = new String(byte_array, "UTF-8");
        // pow=byte_array.to;
        for (i = 0; i < byte_array.length; i++) {
            double input = byte_array[i];
            double t1 = Math.pow(e, -1);
            double t2 = n % 2;
            double encrypt = (Math.pow(input, e)) * t2;//formula
            double p_k = t1 * t2;
            double decrypt = (Math.pow(en, p_k)) * t2;//formula
            }}
```

Here my input is byte[] and decrypted value is double.So i want to convert decrypt(double) in to original text file content. how to proceed?

Comment: I think I understand, but you might be better to edit your question to include examples of input and your expected output, to ensure that you get useful answers.

Comment: It looks like your spacebar threw up all over your code. Mind cleaning that up?

Comment: expected Encryption and Decryption formula gives same result. then convert the decryption value in to text.

Comment: Actually, on re-reading your question, I think I have misunderstood what you are being asked to do.  Could you please check the requirements.  Are they asking you to convert the text to a single number and encode / decode that using the formulae ... or are they asking you to convert the text into a sequence of numbers that you encode / decode individually?

Comment: i meant to  convert the text into a sequence of numbers to encode / decode individually by using double and byte array.  That time i couldn't complete the task. give idea to do.

Comment: they are asking to convert the text either single or sequence of number. which one can proceed?

Comment: please give your valuable response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally....I found Solution..

```
     public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
    sp1.setVisible(true);
    String k = t2.getText();
    e = Integer.valueOf(k);
    d = (Math.pow(e, -1)) * (n % 2);
    System.out.println("d=" + d);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String eof_line;
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    while ((eof_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        arr = eof_line.toCharArray();
        byte_array = eof_line.getBytes();
        for (i = 0; i < byte_array.length; i++) {
            ta1.append(Integer.toString(byte_array[i]));
            double input = byte_array[i];
            double t1 = Math.pow(e, -1);
            double t2 = n % 2;
            double en = (Math.pow(input, e)) * t2;
            p_key = t1 * t2;
            double de = (Math.pow(en, p_key)) * t2;
            b = (char) java.lang.Math.round(de);
            ta2.append("" + b);
            }
            br.close();
            return null;
          }
```

Comment: Since cryptography is generally done using arbitrary-precision *integers* (no decimals involved) you should use `BigInteger` instead of `double`